# Handle long key presses in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to get keys from users using Javascript and storing it in a Javascript object.

i.e. when I press <kbd>A</kbd>, 1 should be added to myJSON[65].
The following code works perfectly but if users press a key for a long time it will detect it as multiple key presses. I don't wan't that. Is there a better way to do this?

```js
var myJSON={65:[],83:[],68:[],70:[],71:[]};
window.onkeydown=function(e){
    console.log(myJSON);
    myJSON[parseInt(e.keyCode)].push(1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mp2v7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var keyStopper = false;

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (keyStopper) {
        return e.keyCode;
    }
    keyStopper = true;
    console.log(myJSON);
    myJSON[parseInt(e.keyCode)].push(1);
};

window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    keyStopper = false;
};
```

Comment: then replace the return with the thing you want to do if a key was pressed multiple times ...

Answer (score 0):

Try keyup:

```
var myJSON={65:[],83:[],68:[],70:[],71:[]};
window.onkeyup=function(e){
    console.log(myJSON);
    myJSON[parseInt(e.keyCode)].push(1);
}
```

Comment: the thing is i am making a music keyboard. i need both onkeydown (to detect that key has been pressed and start playing music) and onkeyup (to stop playing music when user lifts the key)

Answer (score 0):

I use `key.repeat` as shown in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat) it can be used for understanding if a key is repeated:

```html
<body>
<input placeholder="Click here, then press down a key." size="40" />
<p id="log"></p>
</body>
<script>
    const input = document.querySelector("input");
    const log = document.getElementById("log");
    input.addEventListener("keydown", logKey);
    function logKey(e) {
      if (!e.repeat) {
        log.textContent += `-${e.key} short pressed`;
      } else{
        log.textContent += `-${e.key} long Pressed`;
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use keydown and keyup events only. They work as their name implies, keydown : a single event when a key is pressed. keyup - a single event when the key is released.

Comment: If the key is pressed for a longer time, the keydown event will be fired multiple times. At least with my combination of JavaScript, browser and code;)

Comment: You are correct. If a key is kept pressed the auto repeat function kicks in and you will receive "key presses" at a fixed frequency while the key is kept pressed.